# WooCommerce checkout "create an account" tickbox conditional messaging

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce Points and Rewards to issue loyalty points, but this only works if users create an account. I want users to see a message that they won't earn loyalty points if they don't login or create an account.

I have successfully implemented the following notice for users who are not logged in. Clicking the "Create an account" tick box at checkout doesn't actually log customers in, so I need a notice that can appear/dissapear based on the user selection of the "Create an account" tick box please.

```
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'my_custom_message1');
function my_custom_message1() {
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wc_print_notice( __('You are ordering as a guest, loyalty points will not be earned'), 'notice' );
}
}
```

I want to keep the option to checkout as guest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correct. You can add a wrapper to your notice and set some "id" to it. Then using jquery you can check the if the checkbox is checked or not and based on that you can show/hide the notice.